# BigDecimal getting rounded..but i do not want any rounding

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In my code i want to insert into db without any rounding or exponentiation ..but it is converted in my java code when i use a sop as 2.631578947368421E-7

Below is the code i use:

```
BigDecimal a =new BigDecimal(0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632,MathContext.DECIMAL64);
System.out.println(a);
```

I just want it to be maintained as it is because i want to do some calculations .

Please do provide me an apt solution.

Comment: It might be getting rounded from the very same moment the VM tries to interpret it as a primitive constant value. Have you tried passing it in as a `String` ?

Comment: Out of interest, what calculations do you have which require 40 digits of accuracy?

Comment: @lawrey..one of our payment calculations in our application is generating reports wrongly when such low values occur...so i thought of removing the conversion to scientific notation to address this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Construct the big decimal [using a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29), otherwise the constant you enter gets rounded before it is passed as argument to the constructor of `BigDecimal`.

So write something like this:

```
BigDecimal a =new BigDecimal("0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632");
System.out.println(a.toPlainString());
```

And all should work.

EDIT: you should also get rid of the second argument of the constructor as
`static MathContext.DECIMAL64` means: `A MathContext object with a precision setting matching the IEEE 754R Decimal64 format, 16 digits, and a rounding mode of HALF_EVEN, the IEEE 754R default.`

EDIT2: also use `a.toPlainString()` when printing to not use scientific notation.

Comment: BigDecimal a =new BigDecimal("0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632",MathContext.DECIMAL64); System.out.println(a); is printing 2.631578947368421E-7

Comment: @ashwinsakthi sorry fixed. Get rid of the second argument of the constructor. See the edit of my answer and I have also fixed the code.

Comment: Still the same problem: BigDecimal a =new BigDecimal("0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632");
  System.out.println(a);  prints 2.631578947368421052631578947368421052632E-7

Comment: see [here](http://ideone.com/2paL31), ah sorry, you should also use `a.toPlainString()` in the `println`. Again I fixed this in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MathContext.UNLIMITED.

```
BigDecimal a =new BigDecimal(0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632,MathContext.UNLIMITED);
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a.toPlainString());
```

When you print value you can use [BigDecimal.toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29) to return "a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field".

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. The value is mangled beyond the 22nd decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

> BIgDecimal getting rounded.

No it isn't. `BigDecimal` has nothing to do with it.  The constant value `0.0000002631578947368421052631578947368421052632` is getting rounded. It cannot be represented exactly in floating-point.If you want an accurate BigDecimal with this value, use `new BigDecimal(String).`